# doAfterTextChanged{} kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-edittext

I'm trying to write an application in which the user can write a text, and control its text size by typing the size he wants in an Edittext field in a fragment container and the text he wrote at first in an Edittext should change its size immediately
I keep getting a null issue, the text in the main edittext isn't' passed.
how to implement "doAfterTextChanged{}" correctly?

here is my code in the fragment:

```
class font_fragment : Fragment() {
// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
//lateinit var editText: EditText
lateinit var textSize: EditText

private var param1: String? = null
private var param2: String? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
        param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
        param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    //Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_font_fragment, container, false)
    //editText = v.findViewById(R.id.editText)

    textSize = v.findViewById(R.id.textSize)
  

    textSize.doAfterTextChanged {
       v.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)?.setTextSize(textSize.text.toString().toFloat())
    }

    return v
}
}
```

and this is my main XML ( containing the EditText):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="394dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/red_boarded_back"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="385dp"
        android:layout_height="410dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_boarder_back"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="test"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Write your text here.."
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="176dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="save"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.333"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="176dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:text="open"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.627"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.333"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the fragments XML (containing the textSize):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    tools:context=".font_fragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textSize"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="6"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Enter text size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Font Style"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/Bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Bold" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/Italic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Italic" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post your xml file? and do you have editText and textSize both id's in your layout ?

Comment: @rajan.kali I posted it, and no, each one is in a separate layout

Comment: Does the first layout with edittext is in activity? And what's your activity code?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `textSize` exist in your corresponding Layout xml file then you can use one of the following functions with `.addTextChangedListener` in your `onViewCreated`, depend on your need:

```
    textSize.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {

            if (textSize.text!!.isNotEmpty()) {
                var yourText: String? = textSize.text.toString()
                // or convert to Integer with .toInt()
                try {
                val yourInt = textSize.text.toInt()  
                // ... do your stuff          
                } catch (nfe: NumberFormatException) {
                // not a valid int
                }
                
            } 
        }
    })
```